# Proving MLE for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I need to prove that using maximum likelihood estimation on both parameters of normal distribution indeed maximises likelihood function.

So, the log-likelihood function for parameters $\sigma$ and $m$ is
$$ \ln L = -\frac{n}{2}\ln2 \pi - n \ln \sigma - \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i - m)^2 $$

After differentiating we get two equations
$$ \dfrac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \sigma} = - \dfrac{n}{\sigma} +  \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sigma^3}(x_i - m)^2 = 0$$
$$ \dfrac{\partial \ln L}{\partial m} = \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2}(x_i - m) = 0 $$

And now we get the estimators:
$$ m = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n} $$
$$ \sigma = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right)^2}{n}}$$

Now I need to prove that this is local maximum. To do this I need to get second-order derivatives, and check that Hessian matrix is negative-definite.

The derivatives are
$$  A = \dfrac{\partial^2 \ln L}{\partial \sigma^2} = \dfrac{n}{\sigma^2} -  \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{3}{\sigma^4}(x_i - m)^2 = \dfrac{-2n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right)^2} $$
$$ C = \dfrac{\partial^2 \ln L}{\partial m^2} = -\dfrac{n}{\sigma^2} = -\dfrac{n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right)^2} $$
$$ B^2 = \left(\dfrac{\partial^2 \ln L}{\partial m \partial \sigma}\right)^2 =  \left(\dfrac{-2\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-m)}{\sigma^3}\right)^2 = \dfrac{4\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\right)\right]^2}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i - m)^2\right)^3} $$

And that's where I get lost. I should prove that $AC - B^2 > 0$ but it doesn't look to me as something clearly positive.

Comment: Just a quick comment on terminology: when you are dealing with $x_i$, your functions are termed estimates, whereas if you work with the random quantities $X_i$, the functions are called estimators.

Comment: Also, it is not true that, for example, $m = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$; rather, people commonly right $\hat{m} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$. Additionally, you should probably make it more explicit that you are evaluating the Hessian at the MLEs.

Comment: @lokodiz how would you prove that this local maximum is an absolute maximum ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}=\bar{x}$. Then the numerator of $B$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \bar{x} = (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i )- n\bar{x} = n\bar{x} - n\bar{x} = 0$. Thus, $B=0$, and since $AC > 0$, we are done.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much for the solution and comments!